# ASP.NET Core can't see images when acceding by browser

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've created an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API project, on IIS Express it works perfectly with the controllers. I've created a folder called `images` and copied some `.jpg` files there.

My idea was get those images from my Xamarin app using the url, like

```
http://192.168.0.185:52493/img/lucas.PNG
```

but nothing is being returned. Then I've tried writing the url directly into Internet Explorer, but nothing happens, the image is not shown in the browser either.

Any idea what it can be?

Comment: Static files like images are stored in the wwwroot folder under your project (wwwroot\images). Did you make the folder there?  Also you said the folder is called "images" but your link is to "img" maybe you used the wrong name?

Comment: hi, the folder's name is  "img", sorry I didn't wrote right in the post,  I am running in debug mode from  VS2019 and the folder is under the root of my project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would like to access your file from your own folder `img` located in the root of the project instead of the default  `wwwroot` folder ,you need to configure the Static File Middleware in startup.cs `Configure` method like below:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();// For the wwwroot folder

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "img")),
        RequestPath = "/img"
    });
app.UseRouting();
//other middlewares
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#serve-files-outside-of-web-root